# attach itemAttachment to an email using ews java api

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, email-attachments

I am working on sending emails through ews. 
In some scenarios, users wants to be able to get an email (parentEmail) with another email (emailToAttach) attached. This emailToAttach is retrieved from the sent folder and then attached to the parentEmail.

However, I am getting a stackoverflow error when I am trying to do the following at setSubject:

```
        EmailMessage parentEmailMessage = new EmailMessage(exchangeService)
        ItemAttachment attachment = parentEmailMessage.attachments.
                         <EmailMessage>addItemAttachment(Item)

        attachment.setName(emailToAttach.subject)
        attachment.item.setSubject(emailToAttach.subject)         
        attachment.item.setMimeContent(emailToAttach.mimeContent)
```

Can anyone help figure out why is the stack over flow error produced?

Comment: Please can you update your question to include the code which retrieves `emailToAttach`. It might also be useful to include the error message

Comment: @user5497505 Any luck solving this issue? I am also running into stackoverflow error at same code when using ews-java-api